# What does this memory error of cvs2git mean?

Tags: memory, cvs2git

I am trying to migrate an very big cvs repository (12GB) to git with cvs2git. Thereby I get the following error in pass 10:

```
    ----- pass 10 (BreakSymbolChangesetCyclesPass) -----
Breaking symbol changeset dependency cycles...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cvs2git", line 70, in ?
    git_main(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/main.py", line 119, in git_main
    main(progname, run_options, pass_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/main.py", line 96, in main
    pass_manager.run(run_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/pass_manager.py", line 181, in run
    the_pass.run(run_options, stats_keeper)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/passes.py", line 1174, in run
    for (changeset, time_range) in self.changeset_graph.consume_graph(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/changeset_graph.py", line 355, in consume_graph
    for (changeset, time_range) in self.consume_nopred_nodes():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/changeset_graph.py", line 285, in consume_nopred_nodes
    (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/changeset_graph.py", line 58, in __init__
    self._nodes = [
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/indexed_database.py", line 118, in __getitem__
    return self._fetch(offset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/indexed_database.py", line 107, in _fetch
    return self.serializer.loadf(self.f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/cvs2svn_lib/serializer.py", line 117, in loadf
    return unpickler.load()
MemoryError
```

An here my memory statistics:
MemTotal:      4017036 kB
MemFree:       1830728 kB

Has anybody an idea, how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
An upgrade of my **python version** from **2.4.3 to 2.6.8** has fixed the problem.